# Convert from milliseconds to MYSQL Date

Tags: java

Hi I have a requirement to convert milliseconds to Date. Also the date should be acceptable by MYSQL.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Central"));
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println("GregorianCalendar -" + sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

I tried this example but here "sdf.format(calendar.getTime()" this method its giving string in the below format. 
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

But I want Date object also that to be in the above format (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss).

So how can I convert this to Date format.

Please help me on this...

Thanx in advance... :)

Comment: A date doesn't have a format.

Answer (score 2):

We **don't** store dates or timestamps as a *String* in a database. Hence, saving in a particular format doesn't make sense. You just need to save them as a SQL `Timestamp` and then format them using *Date* format functions (be it in *Java* or at the back end using *PL/SQL*) whenever you need to display or need a String representation of them.

So, use `java.sql.Timestamp` as

```
Timestamp dbDateTime = new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()); // or
Timestamp dbDateTime = new java.sql.Timestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

***EDIT** :*
If the DOB field is of type `java.util.Date` then use

```
Timestamp dbDateTime = new java.sql.Timestamp(dob.getTime());
```

If the field is of type `java.sql.Date` then you can either save it as it is if the backend column is also of type `DATE` or use the same code above to convert it into a `Timestamp` first.

Comment: I have a person object and it has a date of birth field and the type of this field is DATE. So how can I store this "TimeStamp" reference in my db ? Here my scenario is I am trying to insert the date using SPRING MVC. So from JSP I will get a string and I am converting this to Date and I saved this value into DB but in DB it is storing like "Fri Jul 05 19:29:23 IST 2013" when I retrieve this value its showing as null in my JSP.

Comment: @Amar Check my update. It might help but you need to break down your complete flow and update your question with the part that's actually breaking. It's difficult to follow how the data is flowing in your application. Please, elaborate on your problem with an update or by posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Date objects don't have a format. That's why we need DateFormat objects to format them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can't have date object in a particular format. Java manages date object internally. However, you can format your date object whenever required using `SimpleDateFormat`.
Btw, there is no point in having Date object in a particular format.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Date getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat)
{
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
 DateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
 Date d = null;
try {
    d = (Date)formatter2.parse(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
    System.out.println(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
 return d;
}
```

try accessing it like this

System.out.println(getDate(82233213123L, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

out put should be Thu Aug 10 00:03:33 IST 1972

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Central"));
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
String date =  sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
Date dateObject = sdf.parse(date);
```

The 'dateObject' will give you the date in the format as you need.

Comment: I print the "dateObject" and I got the output like "Fri Jul 05 19:32:00 IST 2013" and I just store this value in my DB. But when I displayed this value using SPRING+jsp but it shows as null.

Comment: you mean you couldn't insert this in D.B?